# What issues am I expected to run into with removing the tap highlight colour on a mobile website?

Tags: website-design, web-app, mobile-web, ux-designer

Hello UI & UX Designers & Developers!

I'm just wondering if there's any issues (more so in relation to accessibility & usability) if I were to disable the tap highlighting as seen on mobile webkit-based browsers.

Do users use this tap highlight feedback to know they've tapped on something?

I am thinking along the lines of how removing the element outline when *:active* is generally considered bad UX since you're unable to determine if they're using their keyboard (Tab key) to navigate the site.

Comment: Generally I would recommend keeping both the *:hover* and *:focus* states as non-mouse users can use them to navigate links on a page. I'm not sure where *:active* fits into that use case though.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant, what I'm trying to explain is how on  mobile devices when you tap on a link, button etc they get highlighted with a semi-transparent black overlay, my button already has an action/animation to show when you've tapped or clicked on the button but I'm just wondering if there's a problem I'm probably going to run into.
Just found a Github repo for a CSS reset with an issue relating to this, https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/23 although it doesn't give insight in to why the user uses that tap feedback and if it can be replaced with another

Comment: I don't think I misunderstood your question. You were asking about possible accessibility issues coming from the removal of the :active state on links and buttons. My comment said that I was aware of issues around the focus and hover states but not on the active state. I'm still not convinced that there are any significant statistics relating to accessibility issues around the use of the active pseudo class.

Answer (score -2):

Found an answer on an issue on the Bootstrap & normalize.css repo's on Github

So currently it appears to be part of the design to remove it for all elements that aren't in or relating to a form and then to add it back in for those form elements (input, a, button, select, radio, checkbox etc)

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/bf47fc8399ba059d929d2c31585dff6dee3e6c11

Comment: How does this answer the question about accessibility and usability? This appears to simply say that changes have been made in Boostrap but doesn't give any reasoning or justification from a UX/Accessibility stand point